# Is there any way to track AWS AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I'm looking for a way to find who all are using my public AMI, is there any way to find that out?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know the instances or the accounts that use your public AMI. You can see the instances only in your account that uses a specific AMI.

Even if you have a **Marketplace AMI**, I am not sure AWS shares this information.